# Is it possible to use full text search on iOS using sqlcipher?

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios5, sqlcipher

I was googling a lot and I can't find if is possible to use full text search on iOS using sqlcipher.

But I couldn't found any documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, FTS Support is pre-built into the SQLCipher Commercial Edition binaries available here:

http://sqlcipher.net/downloads/

If you are using the community edition you can add FTS support by making some changes to the build logic as described in this post:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlcipher/yIJTYf8RE24/-IC37NU8L4QJ